# Implementing backspace while reading character by character in python?

Tags: python, stdout, backspace

As in the link :http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/ how shall i implement a backspace on stdout?

Comment: What does the link have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

`'\b'` is the escape sequence for a backspace.

```
>>> print('123xx\b\b45')
12345
```

Comment: but i m reading char by char! this doesn't work if i use char by char reading!

Comment: @AJS, I see; I guess I answered too quickly. That said, `getch()` shouldn't show the character you type. Which OS are you on?

Comment: linux! and in my code i m printing out the char by char into stdout.... as sys.stdout.write(chr) where chr=getch().....

Comment: @AJS, normally you shouldn't fundamentally modify your question once it's been answered, but in this case, it's more a matter of it not being clear. Edit your question to show your code and explain further what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Writing each character one at a time to `sys.stdout` should work. Using the referenced `getch()` you can see what it is returning for each key press:

```
import sys
from getch import getch

while True:
    c = getch()
    print '%r' % c
    if c == 'q':
        break
```

Typing backspace on my Linux system, `getch()` actually returns the `DEL` character, `'\x7f'` (not yet sure why). That can be translated to `\b` (`'\x08'`) for Python.

```
import sys
from getch import getch

translations = string.maketrans('\x7f', '\b')

while True:
    c = getch().translate(translations)
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    if c == 'q':
        break
```

Probably there is a more elegant way of handling the character translations using the `termios` module.

Also, if you want backspace to clear the previously typed character you can translate `'\x7f'` to `'\b \b'`.